# show Output from Conv2d layer

Tags: python, matplotlib, keras

```
from keras.engine.input_layer import InputLayer
inp = model.input
outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers if not isinstance(layer, InputLayer)]
functors = [K.function(inp + [K.learning_phase()], [x]) for x in outputs]
layer_outputs = [fun([x1, x2, xn, 1]) for fun in functors]
```

I use this codelines to create the outputs from every layers. So now i would like show my output from conv2d_1, which have a shape from **(328,28,28,16) [float32]** ..

how can i plot this with matplotlib?

Comment: What exactly do you want to see? There's no simple way to visualize 4D data points. Do you want to see a histogram of the weights? Do you want to see individual feature maps? Do you want to manually inspect a table of the weights? Do you want to see salience maps? If you don't know what you want to see, then that's a question for another site (maybe [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/))?

Comment: I want to see the feature maps..

Comment: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-visualize-filters-and-feature-maps-in-convolutional-neural-networks/ https://towardsdatascience.com/visualizing-intermediate-activation-in-convolutional-neural-networks-with-keras-260b36d60d0